# Can anyone confirm that this is a reliable method to charge multiple SLA batteries in parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Found this diagram at this [link](https://www.impactbattery.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-charge-marine-and-rv-batteries-in-parallel/)

[image]

Can anyone confirm that this is reliable?

Also, anyone know the circuitry for charging 2,3 and 5 battery system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Star connections from the battery charger to each battery will give you more equal currents **IF** the wire size and length from the star connection to each battery is the same.

Comment: Will the batteries always be kept in parallel? At moment that batteries are put in parallel, the voltages must be very close to avoid large balancing currents. For example, if you connect a fully charged battery to an empty one, A very large current is likely to flow until the battery voltages converge.

Comment: UNless you specify wire and terminal resistance, the question is unanswerable.  A 50 mOhm string can result in excessive current imbalance.  It ought to be <1m Ohm per cable. or <50mV drop worst case per cable. Depends on length and connector quality.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this scheme widely recommended (from the OP's image source):
[image]

I think their calculations are wrong, as each battery has three jumpers between it and the charger connections - some jumpers in the negative lead, and some in the positive, so all should see the same voltage and current.

However, my feeling is that the difference between the various connection schemes is insignificant.  While there is siginificant charging current, there may be a slight voltage (and charging current) difference between batteries with some wiring arrangements, but as the batteries approach full charge, the charging current will reduce, reducing the voltage drops in the wiring - in the end, all batteries will be charged to the same voltage, regardless of the wiring arrangement.

On my boat, I cheat - I have equal-length jumpers from each battery (positive and negative terminals) to common bus bars and current, with the charger and loads connected to the bus bars, so there is no question of which battery has the shorter connections.